# SQL how can I count "r.land" which is coming from an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Bestemming.Land, Reis.bestemmingscode
FROM Bestemming 
INNER JOIN Reis 
ON Bestemming.bestemmingscode = Reis.bestemmingscode
ORDER BY Reis.bestemmingscode;
```

This currently shows "Land" (for example Holland) Then it shows
"Bestemmingscode" for example (amsterdam) like this

```
"Land"     "Bestemmingscode"
Holland |  Amsterdam
Holland |  Eindhoven
Holland |  Den haag
Holland |  Tilburg
Germany |  Hamburg
Germany |  Berlin
```

That is close to what i expected. But I wanna get

```
"land"    "Bestemmingscode
Holland |  4
Germany |  2
```

Now I'm curious in what method i can do this. It is for a school exercise im stuck on.

Comment: I know that i have to use the COUNT(*) AS "example" method. But i don't know how i have to apply it, i keep getting errors.

Comment: this subject is extensively covered in theoretical and practical books. Use GROUP BY and COUNT to achieve the desire result.

Comment: I'm following the theory as much as i can, but i was stuck on this one. I do it slightly different than the book tells me. I am aware of group by and count but i didint get it to work so i made this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer the following query:

```
SELECT b.Land, COUNT(*) AS bestemmingscode
FROM Bestemming b
INNER JOIN Reis r
    ON b.bestemmingscode = r.bestemmingscode
GROUP BY b.Land
```

If duplicate codes can occur within a given country, and you just wanted a count of unique codes, then you could use this:

```
SELECT b.Land, COUNT(DISTINCT r.bestemmingscode) AS bestemmingscode
FROM Bestemming b
INNER JOIN Reis r
    ON b.bestemmingscode = r.bestemmingscode
GROUP BY b.Land
```